# Debugging Audio Unit Views

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I asked this question in the core-audio mailing list. So far, I haven't 
had any replies yet. I'm not sure if this is a dumb question or a non-issue
altogether or maybe it's just me having this problem. If so, pardon me
but please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Basically, how do you debug Audio Unit Cocoa Views?

There are essentially two parts of an Audio Unit plugin. One deals with 
the actual DSP code (the Effects part) and one that deals withe the GUI
(the Cocoa View part).

My problem is that the breakpoints are only triggered in the Effects 
part of the code, but I can't get it to stop at the breakpoints in 
the Cocoa View part of the code. I have the same problem as the one 
in this old thread:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Feb/msg00376.html

I followed the recommendations here:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Feb/msg00387.html

but doing it now using XCode 7. Yet I still can't get it to stop at the breakpoints.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Joel de Guzman
http://boost-spirit.com
http://www.cycfi.com/

Comment: Are you able to printf where your breakpoints are?

Comment: What's the point in placing the printf? I am placing the breakpoints in places that are surely called such as awakeFromNib. In fact, to be sure, I place breakpoints everywhere in the cocoa view code, just to be sure. No dice. 

Is it just me? Are you hitting your breakpoints in your cocoa view code such as awakeFromNib or even drawRect?

Comment: It's just a way to test if the lines where the break points are get executed.

Comment: Oh they are being executed just fine. So please tell me, Are you hitting your breakpoints in your cocoa view code such as awakeFromNib or even drawRect?

Comment: It sounds like the view and the effect are in different processes and Xcode is only attaching to one of them. It's possible Xcode can only attach to one at a time. Do you have a sample project to play with?